# TI-Basic Outputs "ERR: ARGUMENT"

Tags: texas-instruments, ti-basic

```
:Menu("FUNCTION","DIA TO RAD",1,"RAD TO DIA",2,"RAD TO AREA",3,"DIA TO AREA",6,"RAD TO CIRCUM",4,"DIA TO CIRCUM",5,"CIRCUM TO AREA",7,"CIRCUM TO RAD",8)
```

I'm getting an 'ERR: ARGUMENT' output and when 'Goto' is selected it sends me to the closed parenthesis.
The only thing that has worked is completely removing the 8th option, which is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned that monochrome calculators have a menu option cap at 7. You can get around this by just making the last option of the menu, lead to another menu.

Comment: You should accept your answer so others will see it :)